# How to create a txt file in another directory using Fstream?

Tags: c++, fstream

I want to create a txt file in another folder using fstream. You must know rpg games, right? there must be a save data system. to save our progress in the game, don't be happy if the save data file is mixed with the exe file. I've tried various ways.

for example

```
cin >> Save_Data;
ofstream Char_Pertama (("/RPG GAME PERCOBAAN/Save Data", Save_Data), ios :: out);

cin >> Save_Data;
ofstream Char_Pertama ("/RPG GAME PERCOBAAN/Save Data"); (Save_Data, ios :: out);
```

I have tried this one too...

```
cin >> Save_Data;
ofstream Char_Pertama ("../RPG GAME PERCOBAAN/Save Data/Save_Data", ios :: out);
```

But,the txt file is not up to us to name it.
I wish, we can make the filename as we like.

please help me to solve this, your suggestions will be very helpful for me

Comment: How do you handle errors? What error is reproted? You can use `std::perror("Some log text");` to get good information in standard error stream. Does the directory exist or should be created?

Comment: There is not enough information to really understand the question, but it seems you want to concatenate a string onto a path? For which you'd probably use something like `std::stringstream`? Or perhaps the C++17 `std::filesystem::path`?

Comment: Have you created the destination folder for the files? Are you sure the current working directory is what you expect it to be?

Comment: Side note: `std::ofstream` implicitly sets `ios::out` as default, so you don't need to specify it explicitly...

Comment: Does the folder already exist? Can't create a file in a folder without a folder first. Unrealted, C++ isn't like Python, Java, etc. Just throwing guesses at the wall and seeing what sticks may be productive in other languages, but C++ is highly unfriendly to that modus-operandi.

Comment: Are you aware of the sequence (comma) operator? (x, y) will first execute `x` (if that does anything at all), then `y` and yields the result of `y`. So `("/RPG GAME PERCOBAAN/Save Data", Save_Data)` is equivalent to just `Save_Data`, i. e. the contents you seem to want to store get the file name...

Comment: `std::ofstream` is just another output stream like `std::cout` is as well, only the target differs. Have you tried `ofstream os("../RPG GAME PERCOBAAN/Save Data"); os << Save_Data;`?  Note that you actually should check the stream state to avoid trying to write to a stream that failed to open: `if(os) { /* file has been opened correctly! */ os << Save_Data; } else { /* appropriate error handling! */ }`!

Comment: what you seem to be looking for is to read a file name from the user, and then append that to some given path?

Comment: Side note: About [`using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)...

Comment: did the provided answer help you? if so, please consider upvoting / accepting it. if not, feel free to comment on what aspect ia still unclear!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking for a way to read in a file name, and then concatenate that filename to some fixed path. Try

```
std::string basepath("../RPG GAME PERCOBAAN/Save Data/");
std::string filename;
cin >> filename;
ofstream Char_Pertama (basepath+filename, ios::out);
```

Comment: thank you very much sir, it works. Then maybe I will ask more questions in the future. Please continue to help me sir. I will keep trying to learn c++, because I want to make an Ai.

Comment: if it helped, consider accepting and/or upvoting answers ;). Also, good luck with your AI!